# Excel Text box doesn't show half of the text

Tags: excel, textbox

I have created a calculator in excel in which i have used text boxes as input titles. I have tried multiple things to in the formatting section and text appears clear to me on my laptop however my colleagues unable to see those text box completely, all they see is text box is cutting from the end.

I cannot use cells because of the structure of the calculator, hence i have used text boxes with some effects.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue, this is very crucial thing to resolve.

Thank you in advance.

Screenshot of Calculator page is attached.

[image]

Comment: I don't see a screenshot

Comment: `I cannot use cells because of the structure of the calculator` What do you mean? I do not see a problem if you use cells? Also I would like to see the screenshot of what your colleagues see.